# Pandas: count empty strings in a column

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, series

I tried to find the number of cells in a column that only contain empty string `''`. The `df` looks like:

```
currency
USD
EUR
ILS
HKD
```

The code is:

```
df['currency'].str.contains(r'\s*')
```

but the code also recognizes cells with actual string values as containing empty strings.

I am wondering how to fix this issue that it only detects cells that only contains empty strings.

Comment: why not this: `df['currency'] == ''` ?

Comment: I ended up using `df[df['currency' == '']].shape[0]`

Comment: I think `sum(df['currency'] == '')` would also do.

Comment: @ytu he had that before but removed it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Several ways. Using `numpy` is usually more efficient.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'currency':['USD','','EUR','']})

(df['currency'].values == '').sum()           # 2

len(df[df['currency'] == ''])                 # 2

df.loc[df['currency'] == ''].count().iloc[0]  # 2
```

Comment: how to use `numpy` here?

Comment: This is the first option. `df['currency'].values` extracts the `numpy` array representation. The result is a Boolean `numpy` array. `sum` then becomes a *method* of the `numpy` array.

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't find the dupe so posting an answer:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'currency':['USD','','EUR','']})
c = (df['currency'] == '').sum()
print(c)
```

Returns:

```
2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this to count empty values

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

Comment: An empty string is not a null-type value, so it will not be counted with the `isnull()` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an overview of all the cells that are either '' or null.

```py
df.eq('').sum() + df.isnull().sum()
```

To get the sum, use `np.sum(df.eq('').sum() + df.isnull().sum())`

Comment: Good one; isnull was not part of the question though.